# Java to Wsdl Mapping in Windup Tools

Tags: java, wsdl, weblogic, jboss7.x, rhamt

I am trying to deploy a sample weblogic application in JBoss 7.1.1 final. To do this I needed to use Windup tools. In the windup tool it shows **Java to Wsdl Mapping ** for the following code. I really don't know what that is. I googled it, still no progress. Please help me out here. It is a very lengthy code, more than thousand lines. So I have given just a sample.

```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <j2ee:java-wsdl-mapping xmlns:j2ee='http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee'       xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>
    <j2ee:package-mapping>
    <j2ee:package-type>spclink</j2ee:package-type>
    <j2ee:namespaceURI>a url here</j2ee:namespaceURI>
    </j2ee:package-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a mapping which tells the webservices provider how to de/serialize Java objects from/to XML. Usually it's generated from Java, or the other way, from WSDL you can generate Java objects. I guess it's rarely done manually. You should be able to find the matching Java classes in the source.

I think nowadays you can rely on annotations, and also on default mapping. Depends if you can change the WSDL schema or not.